# How do I specify InstanceName for SendCommand and GetCommandInvocation within StepFunctions?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-step-functions, aws-auto-scaling, aws-ssm

Reason for doing the following: EC2 ID cannot be locked by auto scaling.

From StepFunctions, first execute SendCommand, next execute GetCommandInvocation.

SendCommand executes a file in EC2.
GetCommandInvocation gets the status of SendCommand.

When accessing EC2 from SendCommand and GetCommandInvocation, I want to specify the InstanceName instead of InstanceID.

How should I set this up?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EC2:Describe instances un the step before the SendCommand. With the proper input and output setup, you should be able to get the id and pass it in the SendCommand step.